# How to configure Bundler via Chef?

Tags: ruby, bash, environment-variables, chef-infra, environment

We use Chef to setup and execute Bundler. We previously run `bundle install`, in an `bash` resource with the `user` and `group` attributes set to `target_user` (the bundler operation is intended to be run as this user).

Due to the deprecation of some options (ie. `--deployment`, `--path` and `--without`), we now need to configure them via `bundle config`.

However, it seems that when using the same resource configuration, Bundle doesn't work as intended; we get `Bundler::SudoNotPermittedError: Bundler requires sudo access to install...`, which I suppose is because the configuration file is not stored in the proper place, and/or read.

How should the `execute` resource be configured? Currently, it's:

```rb
# Simplified version
bash "Install gems" do
  code <<~EOF
    bundle config --local deployment true &&
    bundle config --local path /path/to/gems_dir &&
    bundle install --gemfile=/path/to/Gemfile
  EOF

  user "target_user"
  group "target_user"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this `bash` resource run as *target_user*, that's why the error. I think you have 2 options here:

1. Remove the user and group from the resource, then it will be run as root.
2. Add *sudo* before the every bundle command in the `code`, and make sure *target_user* is sudoer with no password.

Comment: The resource is intended to be run as `target_user`. It was specified, but it was not so explicit, so I've updated the description, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Chef doesn't export the environment (variables) when setting `user`/`group`, so if one wants to have a fully preset environment, some variables need to be set manually, via the `env` attribute.

A minimum preset that accomplishes the task is the following:

```rb
bash "Bundle..." do
  code "bundle ..."
  user "user"
  group "user"
  env({
    "HOME"     => "/home/user",
    "USER"     => "user",
    "USERNAME" => "user",
    "PWD"      => "/home/user",
  })
end
```

There are other variables, but I suppose they aren't significant for the vast majority of the commands.